# Does Unity move object by the magnitude(length) of vector value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, game-development, cartesian-coordinates

Most of you may know that moving object diagonally is faster than moving object horizontally or vertically. You can watch [a short youtube tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMwwYO1naCg). If an object is set at (0,0) then using this code.`transformation.postition += new Vector3(x, y, 0f)`.Assume moving object on 2D plane. When looking the object position at 2D grid(cartesian plane), for value x=1, y=0, it move one position right, for value x=0, y=1, it move one position up and for value x=1, y=1 it move one right and one up. When look at the following image, the line drawing diagonally is obviously longer than others. I read about vector, the magnitude of vector, Pythagorean theorem. Assume an object move one unit every frame. Then after 1 frame passed all objects will be moved 1 unit exactly. But when calculate in magnitude[length] of vector the units are different. I mean 1 in X or Y and around 1.4 in diagonal.  Aren't object moving from point to point? Does Unity move object in vector's magnitude value and set the point on X and Y plane? How do object actually move? 
[image]

Comment: I don't really get the question ... objects move according to whatever you tell them to do ... if you tell them to move 1 unit in X and 1 unit in Y direction then yes, the object will move a total distance of `SquareRoot(1 * 1 + 1 * 1)`  which is around `1.414...` and well in the end objects don't move .. it's all virtual ;) so what happens somewhere deep in the engine is: setting a new position changes this objects transformation matrix, and when it comes to rendering it now appears at a different location ... Really unclear where your question is going

Answer (score 0):

Unity is a frame-based engine. So Unity calculates the positions where objects are in a frame, and when it comes to calculating the next frame, the positions are calculated there as well. One could assume that the object has moved between these frames and conclude that, for example, a projectile must have hit a thin object between the two frames.

If you want to move an object consistently in any direction, first clamp the direction with **normalized** and then add a custom **magnitude**.